# Trying to expand sibling div element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone point out why this isn't working? I'm trying to click on Div A within a Container Div, and on click, go up to the parent container, find the next Div B, and toggle its visibility.

Note: The reason I'm doing it like this is I don't want to show ALL divs with the "child" class. Only the next one after the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vecalciskay/54HxU/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="parent"> 

    <span> Parent Text (click) </span>

</div>
<div class="child">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                This
            </td>
            <td>
                Table
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Should 
            </td>
            <td>
                Expand
            </td>                
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>

    <div class="parent"> 

    <span> Parent 2 (don't click) </span>

</div>
<div class="child">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                This
            </td>
            <td>
                Table
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Should Not 
            </td>
            <td>
                Expand
            </td>                
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.child').hide();

        $('.parent').click(function () {

            var obj = $(this).parent().next(".child");
            obj.toggle("fast");

            return false;
        });
 });
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't your fiddle work?

Comment: Besides, `$('.parent').parent()` returns `.container`; `.next('.child')` obviously selects the wrong item.

Comment: it seems that your fiddle is working

Comment: `.parent` and `.child` are siblings. So why use `$(this).parent().next(".child")`?

Comment: The jQuery in your fiddle doesn't match the jQuery you posted here.

Comment: So you want `$(this).next().toggle("fast");` ? Like this http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/y67Mh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, I realized I was misinterpreting the siblings. Problem solved!